# Взять название для ключа из переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Я создаю програмку, которая по коду страны, будет выводить ее полное название. Например.
**Ввод:**
*US*
**Вывод:**
*United States of America*
И я названия стран беру из отдельного файла, в котором они записаны в таком виде:
*US: United States of America*
И записываю это в список, откуда позже циклом for раскладываю ключ и название в словарь, и тут проблема, когда я пытаюсь ввести в название ключа переменную, ключом становиться сама переменная.
А нужно что бы ключом становилась строка из переменной.
Вот код:

```
file = open("country.txt", "r").read()
country_list_not = file.split(": ")
country_list = []
country = {}
for i in country_list_not:
    if i.find("\n") != -1:
        if not i.endswith("\n"):
            country_list.append(i[:len(i) - 3])
            country_list.append(i[-2:len(i)])
            continue
        else:
            country_list.append(i[:-1])
            continue

    country_list.append(i)
key = 0
value = 0
for x in country_list:
    if not country_list.index(x) % 2:
        key = x
        continue
    value = x
    country.update(key=value)
print(country)
```

Вывод:

```
{'key': 'United Kingdom'}
```

А должно быть:

```
{'UK': 'United Kingdom'}
```

Comment: пример входных данных дайте. Пару строк из текстового файла будет достаточно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример файла `country.txt`. Если Вы храните `US: United States of America` в каждой строчке отдельно, то можно решить Вашу задачу по-другому.

Основная проблема Ваша в строчке `country.update(key=value)`.

`key=` - это не Ваша переменная `key`, а название ключа, по которому будет добавлено значение из переменной `value`. Правильно будет сделать `country[key] = value`!

Дополнительно можно упростить Ваш код:

```py
>>> country = {}
>>> with open("country.txt", "r") as file:
...     for line in file.readlines():
...         code, name = line.split(': ')
...         country[code] = name.removesuffix('\n')
... 
>>> print(country)
{'US': 'United States of America', 'GBR': 'The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland'}
```

country.txt

```
US: United States of America
GBR: The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, правда, пришлось удалить \n в конце названия страны

Comment: @Aloterra Для удаления `\n` можно использовать `str.removesuffix('\n')`, чтобы не проверять наличие `\n` в конце строки. Он удалит, если символ только присутствует. Прошу Вас отметить [ответ как решение вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)!